# How to sync keepass2 using scp/ssh?

Tags: ssh, sync, keepass

I want to access/save my keyDB using keepass2 on a SSH server.
On windows, it is available through IOProtocolExt plugin (which contains winscp portable executable). http://keepass.info/help/v2/ioconnect.html
But nothing for unix/linux as far as I know.
Does anyone have a clue on how to achieve this?

thanks

Comment: Did you find a solution ?

Answer (score 1):

You can always have the database residing on a directory on the SSH server and mount locally on a client that directory through sshfs.